# webdriver.io not printing failures following test suite (only when running a lot of tests)

Tags: selenium, webdriver, automated-tests, mocha.js, saucelabs

I am running a webdriver.io test config using the Mocha framework and having an issue where passed/failed tests are not printing to the console after all tests finish running. **This only occurs when running a large number of tests.**

I am not sure what the threshold is, but if I run 7 tests for example, passes/failures print to the console like this (If there were any failures, those would be printed as well):

> [safari latest OS X 10.12 #0a] [safari latest OS X 10.12 #0a] [safari
>   latest OS X 10.12 #0a] 3 passing (40s) [safari latest OS X 10.12 #0a]
>
> ================================================================== Number of specs: 7
>
> 21 passing (70.00s)

But if I run let's say 500+ tests, passes/failures are not printed to the console (see below):

> [MicrosoftEdge latest Windows 10 #5±] 
>   [MicrosoftEdge latest Windows 10 #5±] 
>   [MicrosoftEdge latest Windows 10 #5±] 
>   1 passing (56s) 
>   [MicrosoftEdge latest Windows 10 #5±]
>
> ================================================================== 
>   Number of specs: 514

The webdriver.io runner I'm using is exactly the same. The only difference is the quantity of tests.

Does anyone know why test results would not print to the console after running a larger number of tests?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Which reporter are you using in your configurations?

Comment: I'm using 'spec' currently, but had the same issue with the 'dot' reporter as well.

Comment: So it looks like it is an issue with my Safari capability in the wdio runner. Passed/failed tests started to print to console as soon as I took out the Safari capability. Is there something wrong here?

`{
        'tunnelIdentifier' : sltunnel,
        'browserName': 'safari',
        'version': 'latest',
        'platform': 'OS X 10.12',
        'screenResolution': '1600x1200',
        'exclude':  [],
        'build': bDate
    },`